# Wildfly + SQL Server connections closing randomly and not recovering

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, wildfly, teiid

I'm getting random "connection is closed" in Teiid 13.1.0 to SQL Server:

```
2021-01-08 10:20:23,949 DEBUG [org.teiid.COMMAND_LOG.SOURCE] (Worker513_QueryProcessorQueue9800) Cz9nti5G/vUr   ERROR SRC COMMAND:      endTime=2021-01-08 10:20:23.949 requestID=Cz9nti5G/vUr.0        sourceCommandID=0       executionID=9632        txID=null       modelName=customer      translatorName=sqlserver        sessionID=Cz9nti5G/vUr  principal=sforce-app-user
2021-01-08 10:20:23,949 WARN  [org.teiid.CONNECTOR] (Worker513_QueryProcessorQueue9800) Cz9nti5G/vUr Connector worker process failed for atomic-request=Cz9nti5G/vUr.0.0.9632: org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCExecutionException: 0 TEIID11008:TEIID11004 Error executing statement(s): [Prepared Values: ['(111)111-1111'] SQL: SELECT g_0.Id AS c_0, g_0.Email AS c_1, g_0.Phone AS c_2, g_0.parent AS c_3 FROM Customer g_0 WHERE g_0.Phone = ? ORDER BY c_0 OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 2001 ROWS ONLY]
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCQueryExecution.execute(JDBCQueryExecution.java:127)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorWorkItem.execute(ConnectorWorkItem.java:402)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor101.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.datamgr.ConnectorManager$1.invoke(ConnectorManager.java:228)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy44.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource.getResults(DataTierTupleSource.java:302)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource$1.call(DataTierTupleSource.java:108)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DataTierTupleSource$1.call(DataTierTupleSource.java:104)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.FutureWork.run(FutureWork.java:59)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.DQPWorkContext.runInContext(DQPWorkContext.java:281)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$RunnableWrapper.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:124)
        at org.teiid.dqp.internal.process.ThreadReuseExecutor$2.run(ThreadReuseExecutor.java:212)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection is closed.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:234)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.checkClosed(SQLServerConnection.java:1130)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.prepareStatement(SQLServerConnection.java:3536)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.doPrepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:758)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.prepareStatement(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:744)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:478)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection$4.produce(WrappedConnection.java:476)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.SecurityActions.executeInTccl(SecurityActions.java:97)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection.prepareStatement(WrappedConnection.java:476)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCBaseExecution.getPreparedStatement(JDBCBaseExecution.java:198)
        at org.teiid.translator.jdbc.JDBCQueryExecution.execute(JDBCQueryExecution.java:117)
        ... 17 more
 
2021-01-08 10:20:23,949 DEBUG [jboss.jdbc.spy] (default task-88) Cz9nti5G/vUr java:/datasources/DATASOURCE [Connection] close()
2021-01-08 10:20:23,949 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (default task-88) Cz9nti5G/vUr DATASOURCE: returnConnection(714b1b5a, false) [1/20]
```

Originally I was seeing this when the SQL Server was restarted: Teiid was not validating the connections in the pool and I'd have to restart Teiid to get connections back. To fix this I added

```
<pool>
    <flush-strategy>EntirePool</flush-strategy>
</pool>
```

which I tested and worked. However I am still getting "The connection is closed" errors at random times.

SQL Server marks the connections as idle after 10 minutes. I do not have a `<idle-timeout-minutes>` on my data source.

My configuration is:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/datasources/DATASOURCE" pool-name="DATASOURCE" enabled="true" spy="true" use-ccm="false" statistics-enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://1.1.1.1:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE</connection-url>
    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>mssql-jdbc-8.2.0.jre8.jar</driver>
    <pool>
        <flush-strategy>EntirePool</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
        <password>PASSWORD</password>
    </security>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
        <background-validation>false</background-validation>
    </validation>
</datasource>
```

Any idea why Teiid isn't validating and rebuilding the pool when this happens? If it can detect dead connections when I reboot the SQL Server, why can it not detect the dead connections when this random unknown event happens?

How can I investigate further? I'm blind to why the connections die randomly every few days and do not know if CCM would help debug this or if I should be monitoring with netstat.

Comment: This is strictly WildFly behavior.  There is nothing specific to Teiid coming into play here.

Please see the full configuration examples at: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.4/html/administration_and_configuration_guide/sect-example_datasources

If you are not using background-validation, then you should enable validate-on-match.  Additionally you should specify test sql or the connection checker class.  As for flushing, the exception sorter class setting helps the pool determine what exceptions indicate stale connections.

Answer (score 1):

Teiid does not maintain the connection pools, the WildFly server does. Teiid just requests a connection and uses it when one is returned, which could a closed connection if the pool is not validated.

Validation checks seem correct above. You can alternatively follow similar techniques for validation defined here [1]

```
  <validation>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
      <background-validation>true</background-validation>
      <background-validation-millis>10000</background-validation-millis>
  </validation>
```

[1] http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-server/jboss-datasource/how-to-automatically-reconnect-to-the-database-in-wildfly

Comment: Hi @Ramesh, final question, I recall reading that the default behaviour was <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match> but now cannot find any mention of it in the documentation. Do you know if validate-on-match is enabled by default, or does it need to explicitly be stated?

Comment: Looks like there is no default value for it see https://docs.wildfly.org/22/wildscribe/subsystem/datasources/data-source/ExampleDS/index.html#attr-validate-on-match